# Programmatically open DatePicker in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: windows-phone-8, datepicker, xamarin.forms

I want to use `GestureRecogniser` on an Image to open `DatePicker` in Xamarin.Forms.
I know the `TapGestureRecogniser` part. How do I programmatically open DatePicker in Xamarin.Forms ?

Note: The real reason behind this is I dont want Border that comes with WinPhone's DatePicker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The real reason behind this is I dont want Border that comes with WinPhone's DatePicker

You should be able to disable border with a custom renderer for Windows platform (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/)

> How do I programatically open DatePicker in Xamarin.Forms ?

```
DateTimePicker.Focus();
```

Comment: Note that currently the DatePicker and TimePicker do not open on Windows UWP version of XamarinForms. Android seems to work fine. Bug can be tracked here: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/10909